# Convert large no of records into excel file whithout consuming much memory

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am retriving a large no of rows about 400,000 ++ trough a DataReader and generating an excel file using a 3rd party component. The problem with this is all the 400,000 records need to be loaded into the object model first(heavy memory usage) before calling a method to generate an excel file.

Any sugestion on how to overcome this?, any links or library will be welcome

thanks

Comment: Is CSV an option? You can easily write out CSV files without using a 3rd party component. Alternatively you could write out the data in Excel's XML format - not as easy as CSV but something you could work out yourself.

Comment: Nope csv is not an opion, any links on How to write to Excel format will be helpful thanks

Comment: Please be more specific next time

Comment: @Artur Mustafin: I have mention the word excel files 3 times in my question no where did i mention csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had done this in two steps , 
  First generate csv file.
  Next Import the CSV to excel ( This can be done in .net by referencing the office object).    In macro it is some thing like this:

```
 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= TEXT;C:\mcsv.csv",Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "mcsv"
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    End With
```

It should be matter of seconds for whole process.

Answer (score 0):

You can always read data from DataReader row by row and store them (i.e. to temp file) - thus avoiding to load them together. However, if you are using 3rd party component for the excel file, I'm afraid there will always be a moment when all the data will remain in memory - at least just before closing the document.

If the performance is the top target, I would think about generating a CSV document by hand (which can be easily done in a stream, so that you avoid loading all the data to memory). There are several free implementations of CSV handling as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem.

I write data directly to CSV file.
It's very fast instead of using third party components.

Comment: Is your soution looks the similar to mine?